How to communicate between two systems running ROS on docker?
I have two systems, one is the robot which is running ROS-humble natively on a jetson. I have another system that is on the same network running ROS-humble on a docker. I have used the prebuilt image for ROS provided on docker.
docker run --rm -it  -e ROS_DOMAIN_ID=2 -e RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_cyclonedds_cpp -e CYCLONEDDS_URI="/home/fast_rtps.xml" -p 7900:7900 -p 7901:7901 --name rosh  ros_humble

I am able to ping the robot using its IP address, but the ros topics are not shared between the robot and the PC. I have verified that the domain id of both the docker and robot are same.
Edit: I am now using Cyclone DDS. The configuration file is
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CycloneDDS>
    <Domain>
      <General>
        <Interfaces>
          <NetworkInterface autodetermine="true" />
        </Interfaces>
        <AllowMulticast>true</AllowMulticast>
        <EnableMulticastLoopback>true</EnableMulticastLoopback>
      </General>
      <Discovery>
        <ParticipantIndex>0</ParticipantIndex>
        <Peers>
          <Peer Address="192.169.0.106:7900"/>
        </Peers>
      </Discovery>
    </Domain>
</CycloneDDS>

The robot is at the address 192.168.0.106 and the domain ID is 2. Now when I try to listen to the a test topic from within the docker I get this error
 ros2: rtps_init: failed to create unicast sockets for domain 2 participant index 0 (ports 7910, 7911)
[ERROR] [1727958543.714177893] [rmw_cyclonedds_cpp]: rmw_create_node: failed to create domain, error Error

>>> [rcutils|error_handling.c:108] rcutils_set_error_state()
This error state is being overwritten:

  'error not set, at ./src/rcl/node.c:263'

with this new error message:

  'rcl node's rmw handle is invalid, at ./src/rcl/node.c:415'

rcutils_reset_error() should be called after error handling to avoid this.
<<<
[ERROR] [1727958543.714272796] [rcl]: Failed to fini publisher for node: 1

The docker file is
FROM ros:humble
RUN sudo apt update 
RUN sudo apt install iputils-* -y & sudo apt install nano -y
RUN sudo apt install ros-humble-rmw-cyclonedds-cpp -y & sudo apt install netcat -y & sudo apt install net-tools -y
RUN sudo apt-get install ros-humble-demo-nodes-cpp -y
COPY fast_rtps.xml /home/
CMD bash

PS. The file name is fast_rtps but the contents are cyclone dds config.
